# Expected number of attempts to reach $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

> Let $N$ be a natural number. We uniformly choose a random number between $1$ and $N$ (both inclusive) and subtract it from $N$. If we repeat this on the new number obtained, what is the expected number of trials needed to reach $0$?

The crux is that the limits of random distribution change depending on the previous number. How can we handle this?

Edit: Random number in range [1, N] i.e. you have N choices for the random number, each one having the same probability of 1/N (uniform distribution).
Then after subtracting, the resultant number obtained becomes new N. So, N is not constant. N is changing according to the previous random number.

A more practical version: you have N chocolates and you eat some random number (as described above) each day. After how many days will the chocolates get over?

As a follow-up to the discrete case, what if the uniform distribution is continuous?

Comment: What is the average value they take? $\frac{N+0}{2}$, so you subtract that from $N$ and repeat.

Comment: @ZelosMalum It is not obvious that average number of tries is the same as average number of average subtractions (it's wrong, actually: for $N=1$ answer is $2$, for $N=2$ answer is ${5 \over 2}$ while average subtraction is $1$).

Comment: What if the next draw exceeds the remainder ?

Comment: "Between $0$ and $N$": inclusive ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust added a note in the question.

Comment: I assume that all the random numbers chosen are in the interval [1,N], and you do not change the interval to be [1, new number] as the sentence "repeat this on the new number obtained". If so then your question is equivalent to this problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977628/dice-roll-cumulative-sum  and the answer is (asymptotically) $e$

Comment: No, **the interval changes**. Depending on the random number you chose in step i, say X, where X lies in range [1,N]. Then for step i+1, you chose a random number from distribution [1, N-X]. And keep doing until you reach 0.

Comment: Ok, I see. You should also change this sentence "We uniformly choose a random number between 0 and  N" and make it "1 and N" if you want to be consistent with the rest of your text.

Comment: @Thanassis Actually no, the present problem is not equivalent to the problem 1977628 asks about, but it is equivalent to a problem that 1977628 is referring to. Tricky business...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z(N)$ be your expected number of subtractions. Then $z(1) = 1$ and $$z(n+1) = 1 + {1 \over n+1} \left(0 + z(1) + \dots + z(n)\right)$$ From here, for $n > 1$:
\begin{align}z(n+1) &= 1 + {1 \over n+1}\left(z(1) + \dots + z(n)\right) \\
(n+1)z(n+1) &= z(1) + \dots + z(n-1) + z(n) + n+1 \\
(n+1)z(n+1) &= nz(n) + z(n) + 1 \\
z(n+1) &= z(n) + {1 \over n+1} \\
z(n) &= 1 + {1 \over 2} + \dots + {1 \over n} = H_n\end{align}
where $H_n$ is $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Why does $z(1)=2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust When $N=1$ you pick from $\{0,1\}$ uniformly; so the count of tries from there until the end has a geometric distribution with expected value $2$.

Comment: It seems (from later comments) that the OP meant that the interval is [1,N] and not [0,N]. So z(1) should be 1. Also shouldn't  z(2) be 1.5 instead of 2?

Comment: @Thanassis Changed the answer. Interesting how difference between $[0,N]$ and $[1,N]$ intervals is constant while first corresponds to situation with no upper bound for a number of steps...

Comment: I like your solution, but I am not sure how you get from the second line to the third line (i.e., how do you get $nz(n)$ from $z(1)+z(2)+...+z(n-1)$)

Comment: Repeating second line for $n$ instead of $n+1$: $nz(n) = z(1) + ... + z(n-1) + n$. Thus $(z(1) + ... + z(n-1) + n) + z(n) + 1 = nz(n) + z(n) + 1$

Comment: @Abstraction Thank you for the answer! Can we take it a step further and ask what if the distribution was continuous? I am thinking something like this : `E[N] = 1/N + <Integrate>P(X) E(N-X) dx`. How can we arrive at a closed form for this?

Comment: @RishirajSurti If the distribution is continuous, the number of tries is always infinite, right?

Comment: @RishirajSurti With continuous distribution you will (almost certainly) get value $x \in (0,1)$ at some point, after which interval $[1,x]$ becomes ill-defined. Anyway, this seems to be significantly different question (unless I'm mistaken, in one possible interpretation you arrive to equation like $\phi '(x) = 1 + {1 \over x-1}(\phi(x-1)-\phi(1)+1)$), so it probably should be a separate question.