# How many random primes must be multiplied to make their product fall below a fixed value?

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $a >1, b >1$ be fixed reals. Choose random primes $q_i < p$ with equal probability and calculate the product

$$
\bigg(\frac{q_1}{p}\frac{q_2}{p}\frac{q_3}{p}\cdots \bigg)^a
$$

until this product falls below $\dfrac{1}{b}$.

> **Question**: If we repeat this experiment a sufficiently large number of times, is it true that the average number of iterations approaches
>   $1 + \dfrac{\log b}{a}$ as $p \to \infty$ ?

Comment: I would attack this by trying to find the expectation value for $\log(\frac qp)$ from the prime number theorem.  The log of your product is then about $a$ times the number of samples times this expectation value.  Compare that to $\log \frac 1b$. It is not clear that the expectation value has a limit greater than $-\infty$ as $p \to \infty$

Comment: By bertrand's postulate there are a minimum of  $\lfloor log_2(p)\rfloor$ primes less than $p$  each can be roughly half the previous so roughly those can decrease it to about 1 over $2^{_2\|p!\|}$  where the exponent in the denominator is the valuation at prime 2 of $p!$ .

Comment: To the close voters: Which part of the question was not clear to you? To a number theorist the question is clear and it has a proper and accept red answer. So what exactly is missing in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for any fixed fraction $\lambda\in(0,1)$ the ratio of the density of primes $\frac1{\log(\lambda p)}=\frac1{\log\lambda+\log p}$ at $\lambda p$ to the density of primes $\frac1{\log p}$ at $p$ converges to $1$ as $p\to\infty$, the distribution of $\frac{q_i}p$ approaches a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ as $p\to\infty$.

Thus you want to know how many (presumably independent) random variables uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ you expect to multiply until the product falls below $\left(\frac1b\right)^\frac1a$. This is determined at [Expected value of number of steps until range reduced to a given fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470167), and the result is, as you suggested,

$$
1-\log\left(\frac1b\right)^\frac1a=1+\frac{\log b}a\;.
$$

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to comment?